# Understanding a code about multiples of numbers

Tags: python, while-loop

Lately am trying to do some Python programming, so am doing some mathematical exercices in some [website](https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/math/).

I came across this [example](https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/math/python-math-exercise-10.php) and at first I didn't understand the exercise. So I checked the solution to at least understand the question. As a consequence I found myself learning some coding tricks (like the `while True` loop).

The exercise is simple:

> Write a Python program to find the smallest multiple of the first n numbers. Also, display the factors.

Below is the code:

```
def smallest_multiple(n):
    if (n<=2):
      return n
    i = n * 2
    factors = [number  for number in range(n, 1, -1) if number * 2 > n]
    print(factors)

    while True:
        for a in factors:
            if i % a != 0:
                i += n
                break
            if (a == factors[-1] and i % a == 0):
                return i
```

My questions are:

1. Why does he create a list of numbers that are superior to the input by a factor of 2?
2. And then the while loop is just difficult to undestand. Could someone please explain it to me (I mean the content of the loop)?

Comment: "I didn't understand the exercise." - Me neither. Another good sign (besides the domain name and all the flashy ads) that the site is bad.

Comment: He does not create a list of numbers that are greater than the input by a factor of 2, but a list of numbers that are greater than the input divided by 2. If `n` is 10, `factors` will be `[10, 9, 8, 7, 6]`.

Comment: well the question on the website u have linked where the question is on the below is  flow chart that explain what is happening xd

Comment: @mkrieger1 first thanks for the review/correction of my post, and second yes exactly but why does he do that ?

Comment: @KellyBundy yes, anyway it has some good exercises.

Comment: @KellyBundy to me it looks not so bad what I have seen so far it is actually quite nice u get a flow chart and a step by step editor where u can step through the code and see each individual variable and its value during the runtime. the thing that I don't understand is that If he just read the content on the website he could answer his question on his own

Comment: @gerdadiegandalfziege I know and I tried to understand it but it didn't help me, sometimes i felt like reading the same  thing in the code with no significant difference. Plus am not trained enough to read them properly.

Comment: @gerdadiegandalfziege The question is unclear, there's no explanation for the algorithm, and the step by step editor is a blank box that doesn't do anything. I do understand the algorithm now and it seems correct, but there should at least be an explanation for the optimization. And a proper problem description, of course. One shouldn't have to read the solution to know what the task is.

Comment: good point @KellyBundy he wants the smallest of products that are smaller then !n

Comment: @gerdadiegandalfziege That might be an even more confusing description :-P. "Smallest **common** multiple of the **integers 1 to n**" is an ok way to put it.

Comment: @gerdadiegandalfziege And then there should be understandable examples, not just output  of the code, *after* the code, with cases too large to understand or too small to be meaningful. That page is just awful.

Comment: okay convinced you are right if i compare the side to like leet code and other there are universes between them

Comment: @gerdadiegandalfziege I tried some inputs and understood the idea of the exercise. He's searching for the smallest multiple in common between the first natural numbers [1,2, ...,n] where n is the input. But I couldn't understand the code properly and why factors are calculated like that. Correct me if am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we have here a tiny mixture of mathematic question and programming.

first of all, please note that the spaces are important in coding. see how the code should look like. (with the spaces)

```
def smallest_multiple(n):
    if (n<=2):
        return n
    i = n * 2
    factors = [number  for number in range(n, 1, -1) if number * 2 > n]
    print(factors)

    while True:
        for a in factors:
            if i % a != 0:
                i += n
                break
            if (a == factors[-1] and i % a == 0):
                return i
```

1- Why does he create a list of numbers that are superior to the input by a factor of 2 ?
**Answer :** because the numbers that have their double smaller than the highest number will not affect / change the result. (This is a maths question) you can check that by removing the condition and you will see that you will get the same result (same smallest multiple)

2-And then the while loop is just difficult to understand. Could someone please explain it to me (I mean the content of the loop)? Thanks for your response?
**Answer :** The loop is using the boolean `True` as the code will only stops until it finds the smallest multiple for *the first n numbers*. the reason of the coder doing this because he has used the keyword `return` that will help him to exit the function, ultimately exiting the while loop.

The loop uses the value `i` which is the first multiple of the highest number of the *first n numbers*, meaning the double of the value `n`. Then will check if this first multiple (meaning `i`) is **not** dividable (`i % a != 0`) by the numbers in the list starting from the highest.

```
if i % a != 0:
    i += n
    break
```

this condition is there to increase the value of `i` as soon as `i` is not dividable by any number of the *first n numbers* meaning that the code keeps searching through the multiples of `n` (`n` being the highest number of the list) until `i` is dividable by all the numbers in the list

once the `i` value is able to satisfy the condition below

```
if (a == factors[-1] and i % a == 0):
```

then the while loop is exited through the keyword `return` which exits the function and the `i` value is sent as a response to the function call through the line `return i`
also note that `factors[-1]` is the last item (number) of the list.

I hope the above make sense and is clear to you.

Comment: great explanation. :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment @gerdadiegandalfziege

Comment: do u understand what I mean with my answer?

Comment: Yes i do. In general the question was at first confusing to me too.. but i really wanted to help him... i investigated the link he sent... and finally it clicked.

Comment: yea the question is really confusing and I think the code that was given as an optimal solution is wrong in the sense that It does not accommodate all the numbers lower than the seemingly random chosen number bc as I understood it. They want the lowest multiple of all numbers lower than n which is equal to !n but then it makes form me the code answer is really wrong

Comment: @DrissLeo thank you for the response I have already red it a couple of times and I sure will do it more. I really appreciate the effort. Am a theoretical physicist seeing you go through the code step-by-step helped me alot in understanding how programers think.

Comment: @gerdadiegandalfziege the first part of the answer, says why the code do not need to go all the way to 1. as the result will not change, i mean the smallest multiple is the same even if the code (list) goes all the way down to 1

Comment: your answers I right but the question does not fit the question. The question wants !n and the code answer is the combined lowest common denominator  of all numbers lower then n

Comment: @gerdadiegandalfziege Not sure what you mean with !n, but your earlier answer computed n! and that is **not** what the exercise asks for and also not what the solution does. There's also nothing "random" about it.